# Symfony 5: Problems Importing Slack Bundle

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, symfony5

I am going through the Symfony 4 Tutorial on Symfonycasts and actually I am stuck at chapter 13 "Installing Bundles with Average Docs" in the course Symfony 4 Fundamentals: Services, Config & Environments.

I am trying to get this working on Symfony 5, but when I run the composer command:

```
composer require nexylan/slack-bundle:* php-http/guzzle6-adapter:*
```

I get the following error message:

```
 Problem 1
- nexylan/slack-bundle v2.2.0 requires symfony/http-kernel ^3.4 || ^4.0 -> no matching package found.
- nexylan/slack-bundle v2.1.0 requires symfony/http-kernel ^3.4 || ^4.0 -> no matching package found.
- nexylan/slack-bundle v2.0.1 requires symfony/http-kernel ^3.4 || ^4.0 -> no matching package found.
- nexylan/slack-bundle v2.0.0 requires symfony/http-kernel ^3.4 || ^4.0 -> no matching package found.
- nexylan/slack-bundle v1.1.2 requires symfony/http-kernel ^2.7 || ^3.0 || ^4.0 -> no matching package found.
- nexylan/slack-bundle v1.1.1 requires symfony/http-kernel ^2.7 || ^3.0 -> no matching package found.
- nexylan/slack-bundle v1.1.0 requires symfony/http-kernel ^2.7 || ^3.0 -> no matching package foun.
- nexylan/slack-bundle v1.0.1 requires symfony/http-kernel ^2.7 || ^3.0 -> no matching package found
- nexylan/slack-bundle v1.0.0 requires symfony/http-kernel ^2.8 || ^3.0 -> no matching package found.
- Installation request for nexylan/slack-bundle * -> satisfiable by nexylan/slack-bundle[v1.0.0, v1.0.1, v1.1.0, v1.1.1, v1.1.2, v2.0.0, v2.0.1, v2.1.0, v2.2.0].

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

And the bundle can't be installed.
Thanks for any advice or help !

Comment: It looks like the package doesn't work with Symfony 5 yet

Comment: Looks like `nexylan/slack-bundle` can't works under symfony5. Try symfony4. Or wait till author fix composer file. Or create a fork and fix version.

Comment: thanks, that explains the error!
iam pretty new to composer and symfony framework actually. is there an easy way to get my files from my symfony 5 application to an empty symfony 4.4 project ? so i don't have to redo the course from start again

Comment: changing your composer.json file to 4.4 and update should be enough